# how do I check if the user has Notification Center turned on

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

When I use [UIApplication enabledRemoteNotificationTypes], I'm only able to see if the user has turned on alerts, sounds, badge notifications. I can't seem to discern if they're turned on the "Notification Center" on/off toggle. Is there a way to check for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not. `+enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` is meant to help you determine what you should include in your push notifications; your app doesn’t really get to know if the user’s chosen not to see them at all.

Comment: There's no way to see if they've turned them on or off at all even for my specific application (top item toggle)? Why would that be hidden from the application?

Comment: @Joey Because your app doesn't need to know that. The only thing it should know about is the notification types.

Comment: Ok, upon looking closer it appears this toggle is a blanket on/off setting. I had thought it determined whether it showed in the Notif Center that you swipe down on the iphone but was wrong. Not having access to it is more understandable now that I see it doesn't add functionality to notifs by simply being on.